# Regular Expression to match 1000.00 and 1 000.00

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to match both 1000.00 and 1 000.00. So you know where I'm trying to pull it from, it's coming from a string such as this.

```
{lhs: "1 Australian dollar",rhs: "1 000.00000 British pounds",error: "",icc: true}
```

or

```
 {lhs: "1 Australian dollar",rhs: "1000.00000 Euro Dollars",error: "",icc: true}
```

So I guess a bit of a lookbehind and lookahead is needed.

I could probably spend the next day or so sorting out the regex here. I'm excellent with E164 stuff, but when it comes to this, I'm woeful!

Cheers all,

Trent

Comment: Have you tried writing one?

Comment: why not just strip spaces from the string first. Then it'll be a simple numeric; no regex required.

Comment: Lol it's not as simple as 1000.00 and 1 000.00 im afraid Bart. There will be other figures produced.

Comment: How have you gone from woeful to excellent at E164 stuff?

Comment: Hi @Blender. I have but like i said in the post, it's woeful and not doing what it's meant to "rhs: \\"(\\d*[\s]\d*.\d*)"

Comment: Can you not strip out the white space and then perform regex on it?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Thanks for the comment but I'm only here asking for help! I can leverage features within Lync that helps me with E164 numbers but it's not like a valid number contains a "." ever. Anyways I might just begin learning RegEx myself if I'm going to recieve comments such as these. Shame really, Stackoverflow has some really good community users here.

Comment: There is no such thing as Euro Dollars!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `(\d[\d ]*)|(\d[\d ]*\.\d*)`. This doesn't take into account compiler escaping backslashes though.

Or if it must be groups of 3 digits separated by spaces, with the first group being between 1 and 3 digits:

`(\d){1,3}( \d\d\d)*\.\d+`

Note that the last regex will match `1 000.00` but not `1000.00` (without spaces) or `1 000` (without a decimal point).

**I haven't tested** those regexes, I just typed them, so first test them if you will use them.

Comment: Thanks @sashoalm. I was able to modidy your second one for my needs. Cheers and thank you!